# How do I count the occurences of the values in each row of a joined table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am creating a database for a hotel system using sql developer and oracle 11g and I need to print the first_name, last_name, email and how many times each person (email) visited the hotel. I therefore need to count how many times email occurs in the booking table.

I have 2 tables to join:

- Customer:

`first_name`   `last_name`   `phone`   `address`   `town`  `email`   `postcode`

- Booking:

`Date_`   `room`   `occupants`   `arrival_time`   `nights`   `paid`   `email_`

I wish to display `first_name, last_name, email, COUNT(email)`

How can I do this?

Comment: select first_name, last_name, COUNT(b.email) from customer c join booking b on c.email = b.email group by first_name, last_name

Comment: How these tables relate to each others? is it the `eamil` column? You might need a `CustomerId` instead and a foreign key in the other table.

Comment: how the tables are related to each thr..email _ ?

Comment: What have you tried? Why is the number of visits functionally dependent on email column of customer? That's like calculating the  number of times I have talked to a friend by counting how many times my friend is in m address book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT   first_name, last_name, customer.email, visits
FROM     customer
JOIN     (SELECT   email_, COUNT(*) AS visits
          FROM     bookings
          GROUP BY email_) v
ON       customer.email = v.email_
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be one to many relation:

```
SELECT  c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email, COUNT(c.email)
FROM    customer  c
JOIN    booking  b
ON      c.email = b.email_
GROUP   BY
        c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email
;
```

The same as:

```
SELECT  x.col, count(x.col)
FROM
(
        SELECT 1 col FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 2     FROM DUAL
) x
JOIN
(
        SELECT 1 col FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 1     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 2     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 2     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 2     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 3     FROM DUAL
)  y
ON      x.col = y.col
GROUP   BY
        x.col
;
/*
1   2
2   3
*/
```